# How to create object in JSP and access it using EL/JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am having an object created in JSP file like below

```
<%
Client c1= new Client(dbc,id);
pageContext.setAttribute("c1", c1 );
%>
```

And later on I need to access it in my tag like below

```
<t:client_layout title="">
<jsp:attribute name="content">
.....
${pageScope.c1.getFirstName()}//working
${pageScope.c1.sa.getBalance()}//not working!
.....
</jsp:attribute>
</t:client_layout>
```

The weird part is **I am not able to access** the object inside client which is `c1.sa`

Please note the `c1.sa.getBalance()` is working inside my eclipse testdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using a ugly solution like below

```
Client c1= new Client(dbc,id);
pageContext.setAttribute("c1", c1 );
pageContext.setAttribute("sa", c1.sa );
pageContext.setAttribute("at", c1.sa.at );
```

And access it using

```
${pageScope.at.getName()}
${pageScope.sa.getBalance()}
```

Please advice if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: JSTL supports properties, you can `${pageScope.at.name}` instead of `${pageScope.at.getName()}`